# How To Prevent ObjectId from converting to $oid : string Format inC# MongoDriver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to send Bson Document from my dotnet program to MongoDB where I have a list of OBjectIds.
The Problem is that this list changes after inserting the documents to MongoDB.

I'm Trying to get this format:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("<id1>")
        
    },
    {
        "_id" :  ObjectId("<id2>")
        
    },
    {
        "_id" :  ObjectId("<Id3>")
        
    }
]
```

Which appear to be the case before sending the document.
However, after insertong the Bson document I receive this format:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : {
            "$oid" : "<id1>"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "$oid" : "<id2>"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "$oid" : "<id3>"
        }
    }
]
```

Here's how I initialize the BsonArray if Ids:

```
public BsonArray GetSimilarDocumentsIds()
        {
            // similarIds is List<string> of ids
            var keys = similarIds.Keys.ConvertAll(x => new New BsonDocument("_id", new ObjectId(x)));
            var result = new BsonArray();
            foreach (var id in keys)
            {
                result.Add(id.ToBsonDocument());
            }
            return result;
        }

//-- somewhere later in the program

mainDocument.Add("SimilarIds", GetSimilarDocumentsIds())

await db.InsertOneAsync(mainDocument);
```

I tried to override the BsonRepresentation but it didn't work. Wrapping it under any object doesn't work and also I tried to build a custom serializer which didn't work.

I understand that this happens because [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid), but I have to fix it as it is ruining our convention format.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the you "receive this format"? It looks to me like the data is being stored in the correct format, and the output you're referring to is just one particular representation of that format

Comment: Perhaps I should've been more specific with my wording. 
Even though that is not a problem, I'm trying write it in the DB in a representation of ObjectIds and avoid having the '$oid'  representation.

Comment: What user20042973 is asking is how did you retrieve that format? What you are showing there is JSON, not BSON.  To check how it is stored in the db, try running `db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{_id_type:{$type:"$_id"},_id:1}}])`.  Adjust the `"$_id"` as necessary to refer to the field you want.  If it returns `"_id_type": "objectId"` the fields are stored in the db as objectid, and that extended json you see is being generated by whatever client you are using to query. https://mongoplayground.net/p/b3y5Od2Wt8O

Answer (score 2):

Even with the additional comment, the question and problem is still not clear to me. Specifically let's focus on this:

> I'm trying write it in the DB in a representation of ObjectIds and avoid having the '$oid' representation.

MongoDB stores information in a JSON-like format, but it does *not* use JSON directly. Instead it uses BSON. You can find out more information about BSON in blog posts such as [Explaining BSON with Examples](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/bson) and [JSON and BSON](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson).  BSON has a well-defined structure, and we can see [from its specification](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html) that the storage of an ObjectId for a field has the following specific representation:

```
"\x07" e_name (byte*12)
```

For our purposes, most of these implementation details don't matter. The relevant thing is that the *internal representation* of an ObjectId is not associated with a string such as `"$oid"`. As you correctly pointed out, the `$oid` nomenclature is associated with an *output format* that is utilized to represent BSON in JSON while retaining type information.

We can run a quick exercise to help confirm these claims. Consider the following:

```
> db.foo.find()
[
  { _id: 0, x: ObjectId("64c435faef01c4ed427ebead") },
  { _id: 1, x: { '$oid': '64c435faef01c4ed427ebead' } }
]
>
> db.foo.find({x: ObjectId("64c435faef01c4ed427ebead")})
[ 
  { _id: 0, x: ObjectId("64c435faef01c4ed427ebead") } 
]
>
```

Here we have two documents in the database, but only one of them actually has an ObjectId stored in its `x` field. This is demonstrated by the fact that only one of the documents is returned when the search predicate contains an ObjectId. Moreover, we can further test this by demonstrating that a `unique` index can successfully be created when these two documents are present yet no additional documents containing either value can be inserted:

```
> db.foo.createIndex({x:1}, {unique: true})
x_1
>
> db.foo.insert({x: ObjectId("64c435faef01c4ed427ebead") })
Uncaught:
MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.foo index: x_1 dup key: { x: ObjectId('64c435faef01c4ed427ebead') }
...
>
> db.foo.insert({  x: { '$oid': '64c435faef01c4ed427ebead' } })
Uncaught:
MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.foo index: x_1 dup key: { x: { $oid: "64c435faef01c4ed427ebead" } }
...
```

It is only when we attempt to represent these two documents directly in JSON (via the aforementioned EJSON format) do the two get serialized similarly (and, perhaps ironically, ambiguously):

```
>EJSON.stringify(db.foo.find().toArray())
[
    {"_id":0,"x":{"$oid":"64c435faef01c4ed427ebead"}},
    {"_id":1,"x":{"$oid":"64c435faef01c4ed427ebead"}}
]
```

In summary - your code seems to be successfully storing the information as ObjectIds as opposed to containing `"$oid"` strings. You are only observing those when those documents are being serialized into a JSON representation for display in some client shell/application.

Comment: but how to export without serializing it?